# In JavaScript, why does this default destructured object parameter call get an error?

Tags: javascript, null, destructuring, default-parameters

```
function someFunc({name = "defaultName"} = {}) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

if I call `someFunc(null);`

I get `Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`

I expected `"defaultName"` Why do I get an error?

If I call

```
someFunc({name:"differentName"});
someFunc();
someFunc({});
someFunc(undefined);
someFunc({differentKey:""});
someFunc({name:undefined});
someFunc({name:null});
```

With these calls I get:

```
"differentName"
"defaultName"
"defaultName"
"defaultName"
"defaultName"
"defaultName"
null
```

FYI (not part of the question) if change  `{name = "defaultName"} = {}` to `{name = "defaultName"}` then `someFunc();` and `someFunc(undefined);` also don't work.

Comment: Only `undefined` (either explicitly or implicitly if the argument is omitted) would produce the default. `null` doesn't.